# Regular expression for a language

Tags: regex

I need to find a regular expression that describes the language `{w in {a,b,c}* | neither bc nor cb is part of w}`.

I thought about it like this: because neither bc nor cb can be part of the regular expression, any sequence of b's followed by a sequence of c's or viceversa need to have at least one "a" before the c's sequence. This is way I came with the following solution:

```
(a+b)* | (a+c)* | (a+b)*a(a+c)* | ((a+b)*a(a+c)*a)* | (a+c)*a(a+b)* | ((a+c)*a(a+b)*a)*
```

I am not sure about the correctness of my solution and therefore I thought about asking here if it works. And apart from this, is there a mathematical way of finding the corresponding regular expression? Because my solution is based only on intuition.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your expression seems to require an `a` in any matching string, but it should match `b+` and `c+` as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: (a+b)* doesn't match the strings a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb and so on?

Comment: It requires at least one `a` before any `b`; so no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can be simplified.

You can have either `a`s, or `b`s that are followed by `a` or `b` or nothing, or `c`s that are followed by either `a` or `c` or nothing:

```
^(a|b([ab]|$)|(c[ac]|$))*$
```

With [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), it's easier:

```
^(a|b(?!c)|c(?!b))*$
```

Comment: The top expression seems to lack a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how you intend for it to match `cab`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain me briefly what are lookahead assertions or give me a link where this term is good explained? And also, my regular expression is valid also, isn't it?

Comment: I guess the first expression was meant to be `^(a|b([ab]|$)|c([ac]|$))*$`. That looks simple and correct to me.

Comment: @tripleee Whoops. Missed the closing parenthesis, indeed. Fixed now. I hope.

Comment: @JaneDoe: I've added a link; lookahead is an extension of regular expressions (so regexes that use it aren't strictly regular anymore, but they are very useful, so this is only relevant if you're required by your instructor to use strictly regular expressions only).

Answer (score 2):

We could have the following:

> a preceded by anything,
> b preceded by not c,
>  c preceded by not b

This translates to:

```
regex = "^(?:a|(?<!c)b|(?<!b)c)*$"
```

`^` says "begins with"
`a` handles "a followed by b or c or nothing, since the recursion will handle what comes after a"
`(?<!c)` says "b followed not preceded by c"
`(?<!b)` says "c followed but not preceded by b"
`*` says 0 or more of the preceding expression
`$` says "ends with"

To understand how this works, let's consider `"cb"`.  The "first iteration" matches to the third term, where we just get a 'c'.  So, we have a `'b'` left.  The `b` goes to the second term, but due to the negative look-behind fails and we do not match.

**EDIT**:
In retrospect, I probably should've used lookaheads instead of lookbehinds, but both ways are correct, and it's good for you to understand multiple ways to tackle the problem.

Comment: What about `a` followed by `a`? I would simply omit `[bc]?` from the first term, as the top-level repetition operator handles the recursion.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, just changed it to what amounts to what Tim changed his answer to, but using lookbehinds instead of lookaheads.